# how to detect that microphone is on or off in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

**Its not duplicate**

I have a python code that uses speech recognition and it has a problem when microphone is off so i want to add a code that closes python if microphone is off and if its not then runs the whole script.

**for example:**

```
import speech_recognition as sr

#if microphone is on :
    r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print(audio)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print('google did not understand what you said')
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print('errpr' + "; {0}".format(e))

#else
    print('please turn your microphone on and open again')
    quit()
```

any ideas how to do that?

**Its not a duplicate question and it's completely a different question**

[In this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797572/how-to-see-if-there-is-one-microphone-active-using-python) : we can detect that microphone is connected to pc or not , i wanna detect that microphone button is on or off.

Actually my codes has this error that when my microphone is off and i run the code then i turn that on while code is still running , it will not recognize my voice , so i want to warn user to turn his microphone on then restart program.

Comment: An example code that demonstrates this "problem" as well as better describing what the problem actually is would be great. At very least you need to add an abstract to your code and state what libraries you are using.

Comment: Chck this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797572/how-to-see-if-there-is-one-microphone-active-using-python

Comment: @Kenly i tried that but when i print `windll.winmm.waveInGetNumDevs()` it would print`'1'` when microphone is on or off ,actually it detects that microphone is connected or not, i want it to detect that microphone device is on or off

Comment: i think you cant do that because when you open recording tab in sound options you can see microphone is ticked on both times microphone is on or off and it would be ticked as off just when you disconnect it from PC and python script can just detect what windows detects , so first find out a way in windows to detect microphone button is on or off then you can use python scripts, until then you can use the way @Kenly said :)

Comment: when i turn it on it has a sound, can i code that when it hears that sound warn user?